# mc: edit skin color

Tags: colors, mc

I am trying to edit color skins for midnight commander. When using 256 color palette, the colors are called `color1` to `color255`. I am looking for particular tone of blue. Is there a palette of all 256 colors, where I can choose from? So that I can actually see that `color24` is dark blue, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the [xterm-256 colors chart](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use names `rgb000` to `rgb555`, and `gray0` to `gray23`. See the sand256.ini skin definition file for details. Also the `256colors2.pl` script from xterm's source might come handy.